# Keras: My model trains without any given labels. How's it possible?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

Yesterday I created my first convolutional neural network in keras but I forgot to add labels and it trained ... somehow, and I have no idea how. Can someone explain how the heck it trained without any labels given?

Jupyter Notebook:
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/getrasa/Jupyter-Notebook-Share/blob/master/Untitled.ipynb

Folder structure
files/ train/
 dogs/
  dog.0.jpg
 ...
 cats/
  cat.0.jpg
...
files/ validation/
 dogs/
  dog.1301.jpg
 ...
 cats/
  cat.1301.jpg
files/test/
 (1-13images).jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic here. From the docs:

> flow_from_directory(directory): Takes the path to a directory, and
>   generates batches of augmented/normalized data. Yields batches
>   indefinitely, in an infinite loop.
>
> Arguments:
>
> directory: path to the target directory. It should contain one
>   subdirectory per class. Any PNG, JPG or BMP images inside each of the
>   subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator

As long as your data is split into subdirectories that correspond to your classes, `ImageDataGenerator` will produce labels out of these. For instance, take this directory structure:

```
train/
   cat/
   dog/
   eel/
```

The `flow_from_directory` will by default take these as categorical and use one-hot encoding in the background. That's how you get labels.

One final note: since you have only two classes, you can consider changing `class_mode` to `binary`.